# Can the One Ring change in size?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-one-ring

**Does the One Ring change size with its bearer?**

**Being that the ring is magical, does it conform to the ring bearer's hand size?**

In the very first battle scene Sauron get his fingers cut off, then Isildur picks up the ring and it lays in his palm.

In this scene the ring is huge, even in the hand of a human:

[image: The One Ring in the hand of Isildur]

But then you see Bilbo Baggins hold the ring, it is much, much smaller. BUT, remember, Bilbo is a halfling and is supposed to be half the size of a human:

[image: The One ring in the hand of Bilbo]

There is a distinct size difference in the ring, does it change size with its carrier? Being that it is magical I can see that this could happen.

Comment: Yes, it does. (I think this question has been asked here before, but can't find it now.) For instance, it enlarged itself in order to slip off Gollum's finger before Bilbo first found it in *The Hobbit*.

Comment: I'm 99% sure the ring actually changes size on-screen when Isildur picks it up, I'm not sure what else you want to know?

Comment: Is the question about the movie, the books, or both?

Comment: Related question: [Why doesn't the "One Ring" make itself impossible to remove?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/115640)

Comment: @KutuluMike, does it? I put in the correct YouTube video and I can't see it change? Can you tell me the time in the video when it does?

Comment: @KyloRen - That's not the right clip--the ring isn't shown changing size in the opening, but in the later scene where Gandalf goes to Minas Tirith to research the ring in the library, and he finds an account by Isildur discussing it. KutuluMike included a youtube link to the correct scene in a comment on Shamshiel's answer.

Comment: @Hypnosifl, ahh I see know, someone needs to put that in an answer.

Comment: `One size to fit them all`.

Comment: It doesn't just change size, it gets on and off its chain with no effort.

Comment: This sounds like the premise of an SMBC cartoon, where you get a halfling and giant to pass the ring back and forth, using the size-changing properties to run some kind of turbine that powers the Middle-Earth electrical grid.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Yes. At the very least, it *seemed* to.

> ‘Bilbo knew no more than he told you, I am sure,’ said Gandalf. ‘He would certainly never have passed on to you anything that he thought would be a danger, even though I promised to look after you. He thought the ring was very beautiful, and very useful at need; and if anything was wrong or queer, it was himself. He said that it was “growing on his mind”, and he was always worrying about it; but he did not suspect that the ring itself was to blame. **Though he had found out that the thing needed looking after; it did not seem always of the same size or weight; it shrank or expanded in an odd way, and might suddenly slip off a finger where it had been tight.’**
>
> ‘Yes, he warned me of that in his last letter,’ said Frodo, ‘so I have always kept it on its chain.’

(LotR, Fellowship of the Ring, Shadows of the Past)

> ‘A Ring of Power looks after itself, Frodo. It may slip off treacherously, but its keeper never abandons it

(LotR, Fellowship of the Ring, Shadows of the Past)

Isildur also reported that it shrank:

> It was hot when I first took it, hot as a glede, and my hand was scorched, so that I doubt if ever again I shall be free of the pain of it. Yet even as I write it is cooled, and it seemeth to shrink, though it loseth neither its beauty nor its shape. Already the writing upon it, which at first was as clear as red flame, fadeth and is now only barely to be read.

(LotR, Fellowship of the Ring, The Council of Elrond)

Comment: Of these, the first two are not really the Ring changing to fit a new bearer, but the third may well be.

Comment: Well, in my mind, the confirmation that it does change size together with the fact Sauron, Isildur, Gollum, Frodo, and Sam all had it fit on their finger is *pretty* good evidence of such. But for all we know, they all had the same ring size. (Unlikely, of course.) :)

Comment: Clip from the movie of Isildur's account: https://youtu.be/X1WWCCHM9d8?t=4m6s

Comment: I knew size mattered!

Comment: @Shamshiel - Kylo Ren was apparently more interested in the film version than the books (see the comments thread on the original question), but if you want to put that clip KutuluMike linked to in a comment into your answer to show that the movie also depicts the ring as being able to change size, I bet your answer would get accepted.

Comment: Fun fact: The Ring can not only change its size, but can even take "ghost form". Sauron created it around the middle of the Second Age and was in its possession at the fall of Numenor some 500-600 years later (where his body was killed). Sauron's spirit rose again from below the seas, and he _somehow_ still had The Ring afterwards.

Comment: @Hypnosifl I was confused until I realized that by "Kylo Ren" you meant OP.

Comment: The video has been blocked, so I removed it from the post.

Answer (score 9):

Clip from the movie of Isildur's account showing the ring adapting its size:

The ring isn't shown changing size in the opening, but in the later scene where Gandalf goes to Minas Tirith to research the ring in the library, and he finds an account by Isildur discussing it.

Comment: This video appears to be dead, due to copyright issues.