# Would the One Ring work if it was worn on the toe instead of the finger?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-one-ring

Would the One Ring work if it was worn on someone’s toe instead of their finger?

Comment: You are opening up all sorts of possibilities with this question!

Comment: Well, there is [a Jack Black and Sarah Michelle Geller parody video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6LIHDoWDKY) where the One Ring was worn...elsewhere.

Comment: It'd probably fall off even more easily....

Comment: One Prince Albert to rule the all...

Comment: The one "toe" ring to rule them all...

Comment: @Thunderforge, I really hope they went invisible.

Comment: I think this question should be clarified that it means "make you invisible", not all the other "influences" that it has on you, which happen even if you aren't wearing it on an appendage.

Comment: @Thunderforge I imagine it'd be horrible when the Ring became heavier or tighter

Answer (score 41):

Depends what you mean by ***work***.

The ring has power even when not being worn.

In *The Lord of the Rings* orcs are scared by the presence of the ring

> It stopped short aghast. For what it saw was not a small frightened hobbit trying to hold a steady sword: it saw a great silent shape, cloaked in a grey shadow, looming against the wavering light behind; in one hand it held a sword, the very light of which was a bitter pain, the other was clutched at its breast, but held concealed some nameless menace of power and doom.

Later Sam has a vision of the power the ring holds while being worn around Frodo's neck.

> Then suddenly, as before under the eaves of the Emyn Muil, Sam saw these two rivals with other vision. A crouching shape, scarcely more than the shadow of a living thing, a creature now wholly ruined and defeated, yet filled with a hideous lust and rage; and before it stood stern, untouchable now by pity, a figure robed in white, but at its breast it held a wheel of fire. Out of the fire there spoke a commanding voice. ‘Begone, and trouble me no more! If you touch me ever again, you shall be cast yourself into the Fire of Doom.’ The crouching shape backed away, terror in its blinking eyes, and yet at the same time insatiable desire.

If you mean "would you turn invisible if you put it on your toe (or other appendage)<sup>1</sup>" the answer is probably yes, but we can't be sure as we never see a Toe-ring of power

1. Possibly outside the remit of this site

Comment: +1 for the parenthesis about earrings and nose-rings.

Comment: Ah, but we DO see it worn elsewhere in the MTV video awards of...1998 I think it was, with Jack Black and Sarah Michelle Geller. It was unquestionably worn, and he was unquestionably visible.

Comment: I would say that since the Ring has control over things like its own size, you wouldn't be able to wear it anywhere other than your finger because it wouldn't let you.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo hopefully the wearer would discover it's shrinking powers before putting it on

Comment: "Wait, what are you doing? Where are you...... oh no you don't!" https://kidsdontgetit.files.wordpress.com/2008/10/determined_gollum.jpg

Comment: @Broklynite That was the first thing that came to my mind as well :-)

Comment: @Broklynite Seeing as how LOTR came out in 2001, this spoof being in the 1998 MTV Movie awards would have been an impressive feat

Comment: @Broklynite [Here is the Jack Black and Sarah Michelle Geller parody video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6LIHDoWDKY) that you're thinking of where the One Ring was worn...elsewhere.

Comment: @Kevin Very forward thinking, those MTV writers. So what you're saying is that Peter Jackson stole MTV's nerd culture idea. Diabolical.

Answer (score 8):

### I say yes.

There was nothing to suggest that the ring's power was limited to working when it was on someones finger.

Being that ring [can change in size to suit the bearer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134246/can-the-one-ring-change-in-size)

> Though he had found out that the thing needed looking after; it did
>   not seem always of the same size or weight; it shrank or expanded in
>   an odd way, and might suddenly slip off a finger where it had been
>   tight.’

So , if one were to put it on their toe, you could only assume that it would change size to fit the toe.

As for it working while being worn on the toe, a toe an appendage just like a finger and there is nothing to show in the LOTR that it shouldn't.

Answer (score 8):

Yes.

Tolkien mentions in a letter that a fish eating the ring would be overcome with desires to take over the world... and would die floundering on the shores of the river. If eating the thing affects the eater then wearing it on a different appendage would be a lesser change. However all this is based on a reading of a letter on a blog about 7 years ago...

Comment: That would be interesting because it would I guess also have to give the fish an idea of what the world was in order to also make the fish to want to take it over. Or does it? Great thought experiment!

Comment: Assuming this is correct, this would be an excellent answer if you can actually cite the letter.

Comment: But would that fish be turned invisible?

Answer (score 4):

Well, Frodo does have it only around his neck most of the time and you can clearly see the ring is eating him up, so I would say yes.

Comment: But he's not invisible, so the ring does not work in the true sense.

Comment: One wonders if it only needs to be worn because a naive user *expects* that it must be worn.